# Running dynamic queries on linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wonder, is it possible to make this work?

```
declare @SQL varchar(max),
@query varchar(max) ='select * from Table'

select @SQL='USE LinkedServer.DBName ' + @query'

exec (@SQL)
```

It works just fine if you use `'USE'` to run queries on the same server, but not on Linked ones.

What I want is to create procedure which will run some dynamic queries on different servers and dbs, and I want to pass ServerName and DBName as a parameter to that sp.

NOTE: I don't want to use it this way:

```
declare @SQL varchar(max)    
select @SQL='
select * from LinkedServer.DBName..Table'

exec (@SQL)
```

Since that select statement will be retrieved from table

Comment: Use `openquery` in your Dynamic SQL. and use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, little-known trick to execute the remote database's `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @LinkedServer sysname = N'LinkedServer', 
        @DatabaseName sysname = N'DBName';

-- above are input params

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(4000), @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Table;';
-- or SELECT @sql = DynamicSQL FROM dbo.SomeLocalTable WHERE...

SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@LinkedServer) + N'.' 
          + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
          + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```

Don't use parentheses. `EXEC('string')` is evil, evil, evil.

Comment: Well I'll be a monkeys uncle... I have never seen this before.

Comment: Nice catch there ;)